# Does ``Converge to'' and ``Strict Equality'' Always Mean the Same Thing? If Not, is This a Paradox?

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, paradoxes

Consider the geometric series with a = 1 and r = 1/10.

Then, we have

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}9\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^{n} - 9 = 9\left[ \lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac{ar^{k}}{r - 1}\right) + \frac{a}{1-r}  - 1 \right] = 9\left[ \lim_{k\to\infty}\left(\frac{1\cdot(1/10)^{k}}{1/10 - 1}\right) + \frac{1}{1-1/10}  - 1 \right] = 9\left(0 + \frac{10}{9} - 1 \right) = 9 \left( \frac{1}{9} \right) = 1.
$$

Hence, we say that the geometric series with a = 1 and r = 1/10 *converges to 1.*

Now, (correct me if I am wrong) the given series will never achieve the sum of 2 (rather, approach *arbitrarily close*) to 2. I conclude such because the limit of the quotient after the second equals sign never achieves its limit of 0.

Furthermore, there are many generally accepted ways to show that $0.\overline{9} = 1$; that is *identically equal* to 1.

One conventional way, of course, is to let $x=0.\overline{9}$ and subtract it from $10x$ giving $9x = 9$, and thus $x = 1$. And I've heard nobody complain about that---even though we must subtract an infinite number of terms in the exact same manner as we do a finite number of terms.

But, that means

$$
\underbrace{1 = 0.\overline{9} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^{n}}_{\text{exactly equal to}} = \overbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^{n} = 1}^{\text{arbitrarily close to}}.
$$

Doesn't it?

It seems to me that the only way the above equalities can hold is if *converges to* always means *exactly equal to*.

Otherwise, do we have a paradox here?

Please explain.

Thank you.

Comment: The infinite sum is *defined* as the limit of the sequence of finite partial sums, so yes, the partial sums don't actually achieve the limit, but the infinite sum is, by definition, the limit that the partial sums are converging to..

Comment: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)^n=0.\bar{1}=\frac{1}{9}\ne1$$

Comment: Yes, when you put the infinity sign up there, arbitrarily close means equal by definition of what that expression is: a limit of partial sums which is the "Value that the sequence of sums approach as n grows large", so yes, when a series converges to S, then it is equal to S.

Comment: It is worth noting that the proof that uses $0.\overline{9}$ is not really rigorous. It's helpful when explaining to those without the definitions, but what exactly does $0.\overline{9}$ *mean*? That's not defined in the proof, and it turns out the most direct way to define it while retaining rigor is in fact as an infinite summation. So $0.\overline{9} = 1$ is in fact the same as the infinite sum proof... just disguised.

Comment: Cantor's diagonalization argument is unaffected by the issues raised here.

Comment: @Rob Arthan Thank you, I have deleted the reference to Cantor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your doubts about: *Does Converge to and Strict Equality Always Mean the Same Thing?* might look quite reasonable at first sight.

When we say something like: Let $(a_n)_{n\geq 0}$ be a sequence of real numbers and  $a\in\mathbb{R}$ so that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=a\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Is it *really* so that the limiting value represented by the left-hand side of (1) is equal to $a$, so that the equality sign $=$ is justified?

We know from definition of the limit of a convergent sequence: For each $\varepsilon>0$ there is an index $N\in\mathbb{N}$, so that for all $n>N$ we have
\begin{align*}
|a_n-a|<\varepsilon \tag{2}
\end{align*}
and from that we conclude equality. But this is *not obvious*. In fact we need to recall an axiom in order to do so.

> Here we use behind the curtain the *[axiom of trichotomy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trichotomy_(mathematics))* which states that each real number is either greater than, or equal to or less than zero.
>
> So, in fact we axiomatically cope with the situation. However small we choose $\varepsilon>0$ we can find an index $N\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $|a_n-a|<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$. But this means that the limiting value is neither greater than nor smaller than $a$. Thanks to the *axiom of trichotomy* we can conclude that equality holds.

Comment: Thank you for this very clearly presented answer. I must mull it over to grasp it Perhaps a connection exists between this and the notion of an asymptotic curve (or sequence of partial sums in this case)  ``meeting (at 1) at infinity.''

Comment: @SamuelBowditch: You're welcome. Note that a convergent series  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ can be seen as the limit of the sequence of the partial sums $\left(\sum_{n=0}^Na_n\right)_{N\geq 0}$. So, convergent sequences cover also convergent series.

Answer (score 4):

I'll try to explain some concepts super-explicitly, and you can say whether or not this clarifies your questions:

A series (or sequence) isn't a number. It's actually an infinite set of numbers (indexed by the positive integers). So a series is never equal to a number. A series has a limit (sometimes), and that limit is a number.

The phrase "the series converges to $a$" is just a different way of saying the limit of the series exists and is equal to the number $a$.

The phrase "the series gets arbitrarily close to $a$" is yet another way of saying that the limit exists and is equal to $a$, one that gestures towards the $\epsilon$ - $N$ definition of limit.

A fact about infinite sequences is that they can have a limit that is not equal to any of their terms. So "the given series will never achieve the sum of ..." isn't a problem.

The notation "$0.\overline{9}$" should be strictly thought of as a limit of the infinite sequence it describes. Notationally it works just like $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} ...$ or $\sum_{i=1}^\infty$.

---

Responding to comment:

1 - When you say "the limit of that sequence of partial sums merely approaches (but does not hit) its limit" you're going wrong.

The **sequence** of partial sums **approaches** a number.

The **limit** of the sequence of partial sums **is** a number.

2 - You're smart to be wary of proofs that manipulate infinite sequences (or any limits) just like finite arithmetical expressions. One can get into a lot of trouble that way. Many of those proofs that $0.\overline{9} = 1$ aren't rigorous and should be left behind -- let's cal them middle school proofs.

Firstly, theorems about manipulating infinite series usually start with "If certain limits exist, then ...." and the middle school proofs don't prove existence before doing the manipulations.

Secondly, remember that $0.\overline{9}$ (or, indeed, any non-terminating decimal) is notation for writing the limit of an infinite series. Limits of infinite series are too complicated for middle school, so we gloss over that distinction. But if you want to be really sure of what you're doing you have to deal with that.

Comment: Yes, but what confuses me is that we are taught by various proofs that  $0.\overline{9}$ not only ``achieves 1'' but is 1. Whereas when we describe the former as an infinite series (set up a sequence of partial sums if you will) ---the limit of that sequence of partial sums ``merely'' approaches (but does not hit) its limit. The problem may be in my reasoning---but I have grown to become somewhat wary of proofs involving an infinity of terms that rely on ordinary  arithmetic/algebra like the  $0.\overline{9}=1$ proof. Thank you for your informative answer.

Comment: @SamuelBowditch - I updated the answer to address your comment.

Comment: Thank you for your update.

Answer (score 3):

> Now, (correct me if I am wrong) the given series will never achieve the sum of 2 (rather, approach arbitrarily close) to $1$.

You are .... not correct.

The series will never achieve $1$ *within a finite number of terms* and we reach a *precise value that is close* to $2$ depending upon *the precise number of steps* and we can achieve a result that is as arbitrarily close to $1$ as we like by performing a specific finite number of steps required to get it that close to $1$.

But if we do the series an *infinite* number of steps.....  well, that's a different story altogether.

... Okay, we can debate what it means to do an infinite number of terms and if that even makes sense and if it does make sense is it possible.

But if doing it an infinite number of steps *is* meaningful (in my opinion, it isn't) and if figuring out the infinite sum is possible (in my opinion as it isn't meaningful it's not meaningful to talk of it being done) then, if so, then the sum *is* exactly $1$ and we do get $1$.  Not arbitrarily close to $1$ (we *aren't* doing this a finite number of times and not getting to the end; we are doing this an *infinite* number of times and we *ARE* getting to the end.

More formally we have a *sequence* of terms:

$a_n = \sum_{k=1}^n 9\cdot \frac1{10^k}=0.\underbrace{999....9}_{n\text {times}}$

This *sequence* $\{a_i\} = \{0.9,0.99,0.999,0.9999,......\}$ *converges* to $1$ but none of the *terms* are equal to one but it *ISN'T* *any* of the terms we are talking about when we say the *limit* is exactly equal to $1$. (It is.)  It's the *limit* of the terms, not any of the terms itself.

And we define an *INFINITE* sequence, not equal to *any* of the finite sequences $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 9\cdot \frac1{10^k} =\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n 9\cdot \frac1{10^k}$ and it is the *limit* that is the *infinite* series, that is not *any* of the finite terms that make the sequence, which *is* equal to *exactly* $1$.